# How to export polygon coordinates?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, polygon, export, ascii

How can I export each polygon-vertice's coordinate (every point coordinate of every polygon) of a polygon Geodatabase-feature class to an ascii text file (csv or txt)? I don't want to convert it to a point FC first. I cannot use ET Geowizards! I don't have FME (or is the little FME encluded in ARC able to do this? How?) I don't want to export to XML format - except if someone can tell me how to convert XML to a simple text file.

Comment: Would a WKT string work for you?

Comment: WKT would certainly help, "Export Feature Attribute to Ascii" doesn't help, because it export each polygons centroid coordinate, only. But what I need are all coordinates of a polgon.

Comment: How about this tool? https://github.com/project-open-data/esri2open

Comment: I cannot use executables from external (internet) sources,

Comment: I found a good workaround , here : http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=F25C5576-1422-2418-A060-04188EBD33A9 
it is a sample toolbox with some python scripts that can import and export ascii coords. Unfortunately it doesn't carry attributes (name, number etc) with it.

Comment: what about reading geometry with python and save output as text file. See this link for further info. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001t000000

Answer (score 5):

What about the [Export Feature Attribute to ASCII Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005p0000003v000000) in the Spatial Stats Toolbox? It's available at all license levels.

Comment: "Export Feature Attribute to Ascii" doesn't help, because it export each polygons centroid coordinate, only. But what I need are all coordinates of a polgon. Jo.

Comment: @user23925 Wow, indeed you are correct. The help on that tool is very misleading. I should have tested it first. My apologies. Feel free to downvote this answer.